# Jquery Datatable div as popover

Tags: jquery, popover

I am using Jquery Datatable and on each td click I am trying to bind the current td value to the existing textbox. I am getting the div as popover but the value is not getting binded. Also on first click the popover is not getting displayed can some one help me

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true
  });
  $("#example").on("click", 'tr td:not(:first-child)', function() {
    $("#txtDynamic").val($(this).text());
    $('.change-trigger').not(this).popover('hide');
    $('.change-trigger').popover({
      placement: 'Right',
      html: true,
      content: function() {
        var content = '';
        content = $('#select-div').html();
        return content;
      }
    }).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {});
  });
});
```

Fiddle on what I tried

http://jsfiddle.net/DorababuMeka/LcLxde5a/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the popover on the first click you need to do `$('.change-trigger').popover("show");` since the popover will only show by default on `$('.change-trigger')` click and not on its siblings.

if you want to keep the popover and update the text of each sibling on click you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    $('#example').DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });
    $("#example").on("click", 'tr td:not(:first-child)', function() {
        $("#txtDynamic").val($(this).text());
        //get the .change-trigger of the parent tr
        var pop=$(this).siblings(".change-trigger");
        //hide all .change-trigger popovers except for the active one
        $('.change-trigger').not(pop).popover('hide');
        //show the popover
        pop.popover("show");
    });
    //you can create the popover outside td click
    $('.change-trigger').popover({
        placement: 'Right',
        html: true,
        content: function() {
            var content = '';
            //clone() get updated #txtDynamic value
            //contents() omits the class="invisible" of #select-div
            //html() always gets default input value on popover
            content = $('#select-div').clone().contents();
            return content;
        }
    }).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {});
    $(".change-trigger").off("click");//disable popover("show") on .change-trigger
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LcLxde5a/62/

Comment: Hi how can I display the popover left to each td currently it is displaying in center

Comment: Also when I am Parent child grid I am not able to integrate this code

Comment: you need to use popover selector option for dynamic elements on #example like this [https://jsfiddle.net/8a4myx7q/22/](https://jsfiddle.net/8a4myx7q/22/)

Comment: Thanks a ton one last help on cancel or clicking ouside the document I am unable to close the popover can you help me. I tried as per here but no luck https://www.phpflow.com/demo/popup_dropdown/

Comment: Also when I updated the textbox value and passing it to mvc controller I am seeing the old value instead of new one and in some cases I am assigning datepicker based on the condtion. But not able to show the calendar on image click

Comment: to close the popover just use `$('.change-trigger').popover('hide');` on the click function like [https://jsfiddle.net/8a4myx7q/26/](https://jsfiddle.net/8a4myx7q/26/)

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to hide this when I click outside instead of cancel

Comment: if you use `$("#txtDynamic").val()` to pass the value it will get the first one inside `#popover1` you may change the clone id or generate the popover content inside `content` option like this [https://jsfiddle.net/8a4myx7q/33/](https://jsfiddle.net/8a4myx7q/33/) to close the popover outside you need to add a click function with `$('.change-trigger').popover('hide');` in the elements you define as outside

Comment: Thanks a ton `Abraham` not able to display datepicker I have written a condition as follows ` if (controlType === 'date') {
                    $("#txtDynamic").datepicker({
                        yearRange: "-100:+0",
                        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        showOn: "button",
                        buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
                        buttonImageOnly: true
                    });
                }`

Comment: I got it I just handled in `on('shown.bs.popover', function () {`

Answer (score 0):

You can use use the cell method of datatable to get the value of the clicked td of a table. Here is the [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ishmam/faqea9pw/3/)

```
    <input type="text" id="tdvalue">
    <table width="100%" id="example">
      <thead style="background:#C0C0C0;">
        <tr>
          <th style="padding-left: 15px;"> Id </th>
          <th> Product Name </th>
          <th> Total Events </th>
          <th> Total Revenue </th>
          <th> Rental Time </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <td data-content="Brielle Williamson" data-placement="bottom" rel="popover">Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td data-content="Integration Specialist" data-placement="bottom" rel="popover">Integration Specialist</td>
      <td data-content="$372,000" data-placement="bottom" rel="popover">$372,000</td>
      <td data-content="New York" data-placement="bottom" rel="popover">New York</td>
      <td data-content="4804" data-placement="bottom" rel="popover">4804</td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
        value = table.cell( this ).data();
        $("#tdvalue").val(value);
        $(this).popover("show");
    } );
} );
```

Comment: But this is not displaying as popover

Comment: Can you check the same here https://jsfiddle.net/DorababuMeka/8a4myx7q/

Comment: I am not getting popover